# Where can I find a Large shed with a 6 foot or less height

Tags: shed

So I’m shopping sheds. I’m really not too keen on building one, but I know the basics of framing and I could get something up together pretty easily, and if I felt really wild there’s tons of free and paid plans online that have your cut list and shopping list.

But I’d prefer to just purchase a metal or plastic shed. I’m looking for an 8x12 or 8x10 that has a height 6 feet or less at the peak. I simply cannot find one that large at that height, my assumption is most manufacturers don’t want to have a wall height that is that short so people have to bend over as they get into the sides, but I am at a total loss at finding any shed online that meets my criteria.

The closest I’ve seen are the arrow Newport styles, but they are about 6.5 feet high.

Anyone seen any?

Comment: Hi there! We don't really do shopping suggestions here so this question is likely to be closed fairly quickly unless it's re-worded to focus on a specific question concerning sheds. That being said, it's likely you'll end up having to build your own or modify a shed that's commercially available in order to meet your dimensional requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very unlikely unless you want something custom built. Why? Even though many people don't need to store very tall things in a shed, they want to be able to walk in and out easily, with at most a little dip of their head at the doorway. Average US adult male height is 5' 9", so anything under 6' 6" would be uncomfortable for too many potential customers - try walking under a ceiling that is 3" taller than you - it doesn't feel right. In addition, height is usually the least of the constraints - far more common is a limitation on length or width due to property size, local rules, etc.

In the case of plastic, each different size piece needs a different mold. For example, you can build a 8x12 or a 12x12 or a 16x12 shed out of the same basic 4' wide components (door section, wall with window section, wall without window section, etc.) but different heights *for a small part of the market (pun intended) just isn't cost effective. Metal is a little easier, but it still just doesn't make much sense for most customers.

Comment: Below fence line is the main reason. I’d agree with you if it wasn’t due to storage. It’s like an attic, I don’t care about bending over cause I’m in there 10 times a year if that. Same would go for this storage shed.

Comment: I've seen some manufactured short "sheds" - really more like storage bins than full sheds - that are ~ 4 feet tall. However, they are typically not larger than 4 to 6 feet in length and width. For something bigger but not tall, build it yourself. Of course, except for the small percentage of people who either use a shed as a workshop or really do a *lot* of outdoor stuff (that they store in the shed when not in use), I'd guess most American sheds are used 10 times a year or less, with the exception of rolling a lawnmower in and out every couple of weeks in the summer.

Comment: @MZawg   First time you forget to duck is when you find out why they are built taller

Comment: @crip659, I don’t have much of a choice, otherwise I’d make it several stories tall…

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, yeah we have a 3 car air conditioned garage and that’s my workshop, this is solely for seasonal storage, and yes a lawn mower. So a height inconvenience is hardly a concern of mine.